# How to intercept the permission call from android application before the system performs its standard permission verification process?

Tags: android, permissions

I am developing a system to grant/deny permissions to Android applications' request based on certain scenario. For this purpose, I want to intercept the request call for permission from android application, before the system performs its standard permission verification process. Where should I write my code to Intercept the request call? In `ActivityManagerService.checkComponentPermission()` , `ActivityManager.checkComponentPermission()`, or some other location?